# Combine Prime Factor Code into JPanel - Java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, combinations, prime-factoring

I have a working JFrame GUI with my JPanel all setup. I am trying to combine two different codes that I've got setup and working. The first code was a text converter toUpperCase in a JPanel, and the second is a Prime Factor (not prime numbers) code. I've been trying to get the JPanel to give an output of Prime Factors for any number that a user inputs. Here is what I have....

JPanel Code

```
public class Prime extends JPanel { 
    private JLabel formattedText;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Prime());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Prime(){
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,100));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter a number to check for it's prime number(s).");
        JTextField field = new JTextField("0");
        field.addActionListener(new FieldListener());
        add(label);
        add(field);
        add(panel);


        panel = new JPanel(); panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,380));
        formattedText = new JLabel();
        panel.add(formattedText);
        add(panel);
    }

    private class FieldListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JTextField field = (JTextField)event.getSource();
                formattedText.setText(field.getText().toUpperCase()); // I know this is wrong... I can't figure out what to change here to get it to pull the code below.
            }
    }
    public class PrimeFactors {

    }
}
```

and here is the Prime Factor code

```
public class Temp {

    static int primeCheck = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number whose Prime factors are desired: ");
        Scanner numS = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numPriFac = 0;
        if (numS.hasNextInt()) {
            numPriFac = numS.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("All the Prime Factors of the entered number are:");

        for (int tap = 1; tap <= numPriFac; tap++) {
            if (numPriFac % tap == 0) {
                for (int primeTest = 2; primeTest < tap; primeTest++) {
                    if (tap % primeTest == 0) {
                        primeCheck = 1;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        primeCheck = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (primeCheck == 0 || tap == 2) {
                    System.out.print(tap + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That last PrimeFactors code in the bottom is just something left over from when I was trying to get it working on my own. Thanks so much for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Change the line

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
```

to something like

```
  public static String primeFactors(int number) {
```

and make the method use the provided argument `number` instead of asking for input.

Step 2: Create a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) in`primeFactors` and change all calls to `System.out.print` to calls to `stringBuilder.append()`

Step 3: Set `stringBuilder.toString()` as return value for `primeFactors`

Step 4: Change the line

```
  formattedText.setText(field.getText().toUpperCase());
```

to

```
  formattedText.setText(Temp.primeFactors(Integer.parseInt(field.getText())));
```

I'll leave the error handling and input safe guarding to you.